# Embedable Java-based HTTP server with (PHP) scripting support

Tags: java, webserver, jython

For my Java project I need to embed a web server to provide various web pages to the user. Until now we used the "official" com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer class, which basically works fine.

However, now we want to extend our application in order to not only serve static HTML pages via the embeded HTTP server, but also dynamic content (PHP if possible).

Any recommendations?

EDIT: Nevermind, I found it quite easy to integrate Jython within my Java application :)

Comment: This is quite a requirement. You'll need a PHP interpreter, among other things.

Comment: http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp

Comment: [Here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/survivant/archive/2009/02/php_on_grizzly.html) is a tutorial that describes embedding Grizzly/Quercus.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As edited in my original question, I guess I will go for Jython.